# Clasification - ROC Curve with very high number of false negatives

Tags: classification

I have the following curve as the result of a azure machine learning classification experiment.

[image]

This obviously shows a lot of false negatives, but I'm struggling to interpret this, as my data has a high number of negatives and a low number of positives (I'm doing a binary classification).

I am interpreting this as saying my data is almost entirely made up of positive values, with the majority being identified as negative. I believe that the false negatives on the chart are actually true negatives. Am I reading the chart correctly?

Comment: This post is a little challenging to understand.  It seems like what you're saying is that you have gone through the data and you believe that in actuality there are more 'condition negative' than 'condition positive' instances?  If that is the case, then you simply have an error in the way you are tagging data as positive or negative (might you have inverted them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how the `precision` is very high and all of the other metrics are very low.  Now look at the class balance of your problem:

$$TP+FN=Actual Positive=31,245$$
$$TN+FP=Actual Negative=508$$

So your data is heavily skewed toward positives.  To have gotten a model that is producing this poorly, I think you may have provided the model with the `precision` as the cross validation metric.  The `precision` is a very bad cross validation metric in this case since it will result in poor `accuracy` and poor `recall`.  `accuracy` is also not a good metric as your model could classify everything as positive and get an accuracy of:

$$AC=\frac{31,245}{31,763}=.984$$

For cases like this where the classes are grossly weighted toward one value, I suggest using the `F1-score` as your cross validation metric.  The `F1-score` is the `harmonic mean` of `precision` and `recall` and hence balances these two factors nicely.  Wikipedia actually has a [very nice explanation of classification metrics here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_.28classification_context.29) and [this paper is top notch](http://rali.iro.umontreal.ca/rali/sites/default/files/publis/SokolovaLapalme-JIPM09.pdf) if you even need to understand multi-class metrics and confusion matrices.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what had happened. Really helpful post, thanks :)